# Datepicker - Not Showing properly in Modal View

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui-datepicker

[image]I Am trying to open datepicker from textbox. Datepicker open but not showing properly. ( Check Ref Image ).
Can anyone help me ....

Script:-

```
     <script>       
        $('#milksaledate').datepicker({  
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true
       });  
     </script>
```

Modal Text Box

```
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Date of Sale <span class="validate">*</span> :</label>
         <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
            </div>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="milksaledate" id="milksaledate">
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Script

```
  <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]<script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this:

Is it maybe possible you have multiple inputs where the `id` is `milksaledate`? I think in general it's better to use something like `$('.datepicker').datepicker(..)` and add `class='datepicker'` to each input which uses the datepicker.

When are you calling `$('#milksaledate').datepicker(..)`? Is it on page load, or after the modal has opened? Because if you call this code before a modal has initialized, the datepicker will not affect the modal.

Another reason could be due to `z-index` or other style issues concerned specifically to `jquery-ui`